# QtWebkit resolving event dispatcher

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qtwebkit

i'm playing around with QtWebkit lately and i was wondering if it is possible to resolve the element displayed in the QWebView which is responsible for an event, e.g. a MouseEvent.

I've installed an EventFilter function at the WebView Object with a function like this:

```
bool WebKitManager::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if(mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            // what now?!
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any way to get a reference to the clicked element that is displayed in the QWebView? As far as i can tell, the passed QObject equals the WebView object and the event doesn't seem to hold reference to its dispatcher.

Since i'm far away from beeing a c++ professional i sincerely hope i missed something and you guys can help me out :)

Thanks in advance
Timo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you could do is:

1. cast object parameter to QWebView
2. get QWebFrame under mouse via [vebView->page()->frameAt()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html#frameAt) method
3. use [hitTestContent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebframe.html#hitTestContent) method of the returned frame to detect the element for the given mouse position

Below is an example:

```
bool WebKitManager::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            QWebView *view = dynamic_cast<QWebView*>(object);

            QPoint pos = view->mapFromGlobal(mouseEvent->globalPos());
            qDebug() << view->url().toString() << " clicked at x:" << pos.x() << " y:" << pos.y();

            QWebFrame *frame = view->page()->frameAt(mouseEvent->pos());
            if (frame!=NULL)
            {
                QWebHitTestResult hitTestResult = frame->hitTestContent(pos);
                qDebug() << "element" << hitTestResult.element().localName();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 1):

Use [`qobject_cast`](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/oopdocbook/html/qtrtti.html) instead of `dynamic_cast`.